# Null pointer exception when executing scroll into view script in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[image: Scroll View]

```
ham.click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
//js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
WebElement we4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(property.getProperty("Intouch")));
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", we4);
we4.click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

In the above code, i want to scroll on hamburger menu bar, but when i execute above lines of code i found Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: can you add HTML please?

Comment: which line of code you are getting Null Pointer Exception?

Comment: WebElement we4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(property.getProperty("Intouch")));

Comment: please check Intouch property is there in your properties file. or property variable initialized and loaded.

Comment: what is the xpath for hamburger menu?

Comment: Intouch's xpath is correct in properties file and the xpath of hamburger menu is .//*[@id='side-menu']

Comment: Plz print error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Replace your find

```
WebElement we4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(property.getProperty("Intouch")));
```

with

```
private WebDriverWait wait_element;

wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);

WebElement we4 = wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(property.getProperty("Intouch"))));
```

Second, Thread.sleep(); is a bad practice.  I carry these helper methods around with me from project to project. You are welcome to use them.

```
public void waitForBrowserReadystateComplete(WebDriver webDriver) {
    for (int a=0; a<20; a++) {
        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
        if (javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return document.readyState")
                .toString().equals("complete")) {
            break;
        }
        sleepResponsibly(500);
    }
}

public void sleepResponsibly(int timeMillisecond){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(timeMillisecond);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param webDriver
 * @param elementToScrollIntoView
 * @param blockOption - If true, the top of the element will be aligned to the top of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor.
 *                      If false, the bottom of the element will be aligned to the bottom of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor
 */
public void explicitScrollIntoView(WebDriver webDriver, WebElement elementToScrollIntoView, boolean blockOption) {
    final String scriptStr = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(" + blockOption + ");";
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(scriptStr, elementToScrollIntoView);

    sleepResponsibly(500);

}
```